# Changes in dependent modules cannot be seen in other module in Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, microservices

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

Auth, Game, Gateway, Group, service-discovery and user are my microservices (spring boot applications)
common-security - this is a module I'm scanning from the other microservices (except service discovery and gateway)

My problem is that my microservices cant see changes from common-security module.

This is root's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>common-security</module>
        <module>auth</module>
        <module>game</module>
        <module>service-discovery</module>
        <module>gateway</module>
        <module>user</module>
        <module>group</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from dao -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>Server</groupId>
    <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Server</name>
    <description>Licenta</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <mockito.version>2.24.0</mockito.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    ...
```

This is common security's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <groupId>Server</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>boardify</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-security</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
    ...
```

And this is group's pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <groupId>Server</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>boardify</groupId>
    <artifactId>group</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>boardify</groupId>
                <artifactId>common-security</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
```

I change log's print in common-security but it displays old text.

Any idea on how I can run group (or any other microservice) and to use the actual code in common-security?

EDIT: I mangaged few time to run the actual version of common-security (by accident, i cant reproduce it). I have different microservices running diferent versions of the common security. auth microservice is printing logs that i wrote hours ago even though they are gone and group microservice is printing latest logs.

EDIT2:
[image]

EDIT3: https://github.com/Radu599/Boardify/tree/develop

Comment: the only thing came to my mind is that common security version in  pom.xml file of common security module does not exist. I mean in that file under artifactId there should be a version for that module. could you please put it there.

Comment: @tashkhisi i saw that too. changed it but then i did git reset hard on that branch without commiting. it doesnt work anyway. I tried changing to master branch then mvn clean, compile then rebuild the module and invalidate the cookies and sometimes this works. when i checkout back on my feature branch the master's common security version is running.

Comment: did you test maven (reimport all maven projects) in maven window in intelliJ?

Comment: Yes. I tried "Reimport all maven projects"

Comment: What do you see in modules **Dependencies** of the group's module in [module settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/modules.html)? Note that the artifact coordinates must 100% match.

Comment: Is that project somewhere available on GitHub or alike?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. This is it: https://github.com/Radu599/Boardify/tree/develop. I'm adding some logs, let's say on JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter::doFilterInternal but it doesn't display.

Comment: @Andrey I've eddited the question with the ss. I have to say my application works, only that new modifications are not seen (few times changes were seen only in a particular microservice, but i dont know how to reproduce it... i've spamed things like rebuild project, reimport maven projects, invalidate cookies and restart)

Comment: @Radu The first issue is that it can't even cleaned via `mvn clean` from the root location  where already several issues mentioned. Furthermore `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config` is not defined with a version etc. Your docs (README.md) mentioning to install each module separately is simply wrong cause your configuration is not a correct multi module build. (Apart from checking in log files etc.) also each module contains the maven wrapper... ?...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have no problem cleaning via `mcn clean` from the root location. What errors do you get? Can this be because I didn't give you my settings.xml? I'm mentioning to install modules separetly but it doesn't really metter. you can always make a custom run configuration in root and run `clean install -DskipTests -f pom.xml` on all modules. Yes, all modules containes maven wrapper because each module (except common-security) is a microservice (spring-boot application). I highly doubt that missing  that dependency's version is a problem because app works only that i cant reproduce it

Comment: When I add all child modules under parent's `<modules>` section I see the correct dependency is configured for the `group` module to the sources of the `common-security` module. This should work for your case: when you edit sources of `common-security` and build - they should be immediately picked up by `group` module.